# How to use data-attribute to pass values from database to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress-theming

I have an issue passing values from a database to a modal pop up using data attribute.

My problem is the data-attribute value passes only one value whereas the edit button is in a php loop and should pick the value for each row.

Below is a part of my loop code:

```
<td>
  <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
    <a  href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=woocommerce_checkout&id=' . $query->id.'&status=update'); ?>"  
      class="btn btn-primary btn-xs updatesection"  
      data-title="Edit"
      data-toggle="modal"
      data-id="<?php echo $query->id ?>"
      data-target="#editbilling" 
      data-name="<?php echo $query->name; ?>">Edit</a>
  </p>
</td>
```

js

```
   $(document).on( "click", '#editbilling', function(e) {

     var data = $('.updatesection').data('name');
     alert(data);
   });
```

So I am testing the values passed through the data attribute by alerting it on javascript.

The problem is only the first `id` gets submitted for *all* the edit buttons in a loop carrying different ids instead of submitting different ids for each row in the database.

When I inspect the code on the browser I discover the data-attributes have the corresponding values from the database but they don't get submitted - only the first row gets submitted for all the edit buttons in the loop.

Can anyone find a fix to this please

Comment: `$('.updatesection').data('name')` returns the `data-name` of the first `.updatesection` element on the page.

Comment: But how do i return for all the rows of the database instead of only the first

Comment: How are you submitting?   A `<form>`? Or a `$.post`?  If a `form`, data- attrbutes don't get posted at all, so must be some other method to get them in an input.   If a `$.post` then how are you collating your data?

Comment: i am not submitting a form. Its a button on a table that is getting values from a database in a loop. The edit button when clicked should get the corresponding row elements using data attribute but it gets only the first row element like for example company name. If you click the edit button on the second row it still gives the data from row 1 instead of getting values from row 2

Comment: @MoritzRingler your answer prints all the values to screen on one click. What i want is to print each value corresponding to each row for each edit button i click on that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the id onclick to class and then used attr instead of data and it worked. Please check my solution below:

```
  $(document).on( "click", '.updatesection', function(e) {

  var data = $(this).attr('data-id');
   alert(data);
  });
```